# Lexical or Preprocessor issues Xcode when archiving

Tags: xcode4, static-libraries

I was about to archive for the OTA distribution with Xcode 4 when Xcode is suddenly giving me the infamous `preprocessor or lexical issue`. This did not happen on the build nor release configuration settings both on the device and the simulator.

I used my own static library with the angle-bracket style import. Pardon me, but Im not quite sure wether that can cause the problems.

```
#import <MyCommonLib/headerfile.h>
```

On my static library project, I put all of the header on the `public` section and it is placed nicely on the `DerrivedData` shared folder for the build result (checked), and I have put the dependencies of my main project to depend on the static library project, also I have linked the static library with my main project.

Any idea of what can cause this only to happen when I am archiving it? (it tested great with both my device and simulator).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to some "imported" files no longer be found / referenced by compiler ( possibly "Deleted", either delete from disk / delete reference only).

Try to change:

```
#import<MyCommonLib/headerfile.h>
```

to:

```
#import "MyCommonLib/headerfile.h"
```

Make sure the file exist as well.

Comment: Yap, Actually I have tried that as well and it won't work. The file is still there (not deleted) and whenever I go back to debug and try to run it (both on my device and the simulator), it works again.

However, if I try to archive. I am back at the square one, the infamous "File not found error".

Comment: Hey, it tells you the answer already. `SBJson.h not found` ! Download SBJson from here : http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Comment: Nope, the thing is I have it right there. https://skitch.com/rend88/gjkqg/xcode. As I told you, this runs perfectly fine both on the simulator and on the device (Debug mode).

Comment: You mentioned a key point : running in Debug mode is perfectly okay. Try to compare the settings of Debug and Release mode. Probably the header search path is different. Good luck!

Comment: Header search path is totally the same. Release mode works, but when I try to archive, it doesn't work. :'( Thanks tho

Comment: In `Edit Scheme` > Archive , make sure Build Configuration is pointed to `Release`. If yes, try to change it to `Debug` to ensure it is not Build Configuration's fault.

Comment: Got the same Problem with nearby all of my static libraries… any idea?

Comment: I also got the same problem, any ideas? I downloaded new version of json framework to support JSON parsing in iOS less than 5.0.